# Two color border on ends of my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/R5G56/

I am trying to create a navbar that has the inset effect with borders and outlines, and I want the first and last nav item to have the same inset border on their outside too. I can get the effect with the first nav item because the outline is the same color as the borders, but when the outline is applied to the last nav item, it looks ridiculous because it changes everything around it too.

Any idea if I can achieve this?

Here is the CSS for the first and last item, the rest of the CSS can be found in the jsfiddle:

```
.navigation li:first-child a {
    outline:1px solid #000;
}
.navigation li:last-child a {
    outline:1px solid #383838;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think it looks great if you just remove those two lines. But is what you're talking about that grayish thick border between Motivation and Content?

Comment: Yeah, because the thick gray outline overlaps the black border from the previous nav item to make it thicker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to apply the extra borders to the `li` tags instead of the `a` tags. So the new CSS would read as below. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/R5G56/6/

```
.navigation li:first-child{
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
.navigation li:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #383838;
}
```

The `a` tags have been removed from the selector and `outline` has been switched out for `border-left` and `border-right`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/R5G56/5/

Is that what you are looking want to happen?  I think you are double outlining the last child 
otherwise.

```
.navigation li:last-child a {
    border-right:1px solid #383838;
}
```

Comment: No I can do that easily, but I need another black solid border on the right to get in the inset effect

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a box-shadow to trick border. You can asign multiple in one statement